# Change the cURL response encoding for some characters

Tags: bash, awk, curl, encoding

The response of the below curl command is a json and it has some japanese characters which it is showing in utf-8. I can't share the url but this is how I am sending the request.

```
curl https://some-url --header "Content-Type:application/json" --data '{"key":"value"}'
```

The response is:

```
{
  "Name" : "\u6545\u90f7\u306e\u5bb6",
  "id" : 5
}
```

But when I pipe the respone to `json_pp` it is working fine and showing the japanese characters. The issue is for some reasons I don't want to use `json_pp`. Is there any alternative which can work without installing some external library and work for Mac / Linux  and windows machine capable of running shell commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out. The below solution works fine for me. Thanks.

Adding \ before " in json response , it is required to proceed with python command

`output_with_slashes=$(echo "'$output'" | sed 's/"/\\"/g')`

Converting \u appended-characters (UTF) to Japanese/special symbol

`echo '["'$output_with_slashes'"]' | python -c 'import json, sys; sys.stdout.write(json.load(sys.stdin)[0].encode("utf-8"))'`